# Unable to get *loval values from AS400 DB2 database when querying from node js

Tags: node.js, ibm-midrange

I am trying to query a DB2 database from node.js. Both DB2 and Node.js are hosted on AS400 machine. Some column values in DB2 are prepended with *loval(i.e; 00 in Hexadecimal terms).
Example: Before storing 'ABC' in the database, we explicitly prepend *loval to the string. Which results in the '<3-spaces>ABC'.

For querying DB2 from node.js we use 'idb-pconnector' package. We wrote a select query which gets all the column values. The column('<3-spaces>ABC') which has this *loval is returning a blank. We are getting the data for other columns perfectly. Is there any solution to get the column with *loval values?

Answer (score 0):

`*LOVAL` is not spaces, it is `x'00'` This is a non-printable character that sometimes is replaced by a blank on display. An EBCDIC space is `x'40'`. If you want spaces use spaces, not `*LOVAL`.